# How can I access the STDIN of a subprocess?

Tags: linux, bash, subprocess, stdin, netcat

I want to run the command:

```
nc localhost 9998
```

Then I want my script to monitor a file and echo the contents of the file to this sub process whenever the file changes.

I can't work out the re-direction scheme. How can get access to the STDIN of the subprocess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions that I found acceptable:

1) use coprocess, this way we have access to stdin and stdout of the process created by the coprocess command via the COPROC[0/1] array.

2) What I ultimately did is separate my application into two code blocks as shown below. The first block writes to stdout, that is then piped to the stdin of the second block. This gives me a clean way to buffer data when there are issues with netcat in the second code block:

```
{ while true;
  write to STDOUT; } |
{ while true
  nc localhost 9998 }
```

(in actuality the script is far more complex as the second command provides to-disk buffering when netcat is unable to connect, but the use of the pipe provides buffering so that data isn't lost when a network issue interrupts netcat)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
tail -f $file |nc localhost 9998
```

Edit:

Since you already have a buffer, then you can try something like this:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    # Your stuff here.
    buf=yourfunctionhere
    buffer=$buffer$buf

    if [ ! -z $buffer ]; then
        echo $buffer |nc localhost 9998
        # Empty buffer on success.
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            buffer="";
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: My script is a bit more complex. Actually the file is truncated and re-written every minute (status file), and I need to parse out only some lines to send to the socket. On top of that, when the socket is not available I want to write to a buffer so that I don't miss any of the status updates. I've got a script that does all of this, but I need to get the data sent to the server. using exec 3<>/dev/tcp/host/port doesn't give me the ability to know when the connection fails, with nc I could at least trap for nc closing on the socket failure (server reboot, network issue, etc)

Comment: If you already have implemented a buffer, then you can send it through nc, you can execute nc every time you need and check exit status.

Comment: @PacoRG: That will establish a new TCP connection for each new data block.  Based on the original question, that's not what is desired.  I think if you use parens around the entire while loop to create a subshell, and pipe the subshell output to `nc`, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkfifo X
some_program <X >output &
create_input >X
```

`some_program` will block reading X until `create_input` writes to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using diff and a simple bash script.

The following script execute `cat $file > $namedpipe` when file change. This is the script I made `check-file.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

tmp=`mktemp`
cp "$file" "$tmp"
namedpipe=`mktemp`
rm -rf $namedpipe
mkfifo $namedpipe

function cleanup() {
    echo "end of program"
    rm -rf $tmp
    rm -rf $namedpipe
    exit 1;
}

trap cleanup SIGINT
tail -f $namedpipe 2> /dev/null | netcat localhost 9998 &
while true; do
    diff=$(diff "$file" "$tmp")
    if [ ! -z "$diff" ]; then
        cat $file > $namedpipe
        cp $file $tmp
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

This script take as an input the name of a file. For example try these commands in your environment (whit `netcat -l 9998` running):

```
touch /tmp/test
bash check-file.sh /tmp/test &
echo "change 1" > /tmp/test
sleep 1
echo "change 2" > /tmp/test
sleep 1
echo "change 3" > /tmp/test
```

**Note**: The temp file get cleaned up by the trap, so you can interrupt this script gracefuly.